# how can I disable reloading in a grails 3.0.0 app?

Tags: grails, spring-loaded, grails-3.0

It appears that the spring reloading causes errors with JDK 8u40 in Grails 3.0.0.M2.
Can I disable the reloading in development mode?
Is there a key to set in the build.gradle or in the application.yml?

Comment: related to https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-loaded/issues/98

Comment: there is a quick fix for the spring-loaded issue under the link above. The original question remains valid, though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure if it helps in above case. I use below over grails 2.3.8 to disable auto compile.

```
grails -Dserver.port=8090 -Dserver.env=development -Denable.jndi=true -Ddisable.auto.recompile=true run-app
```

where

> disable.auto.recompile=true

disables autocompile and autoreload of changes .

`server.env` - the environment in which you want the application to run.

`server.port` - port on which application will run

`enable.jndi` - to enable jndi support

You may set these variables in Gradle build.

Answer (score 1):

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35233114/539048).

In 3.x apps you can disable Spring Loaded by adding

```
grails {
   agent {
      enabled = false
   }
}
```

to `build.gradle`.