# Disable reloading in Grails 3.1 / springloaded

Tags: grails, jrebel, spring-loaded, grails-3.1

I'm trying to disable automatic reload/recompiling in Grails 3.1 as I would like to use JRebel instead.
I find springloaded rather limited, but more importantly is constantly fails with

```
File /Users/engrun/Development/projects/grailsPoc/grails-app/controllers/grailsPoc/HelloController.groovy changed, recompiling...
java.lang.IllegalAccessException: Class org.springsource.loaded.ReloadableType can not access a member of class org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$ClassLoaderAwareUndeclaredThrowableStrategy with modifiers "public"
```

I have tried all kinds of settings that I have found available, however, none actually disables reloading when running the run-app command

I have tried

```
disable.auto.recompile=true
```

on command line, GRAILS_OPTS, and in application.yml

I have tried the

```
-noreloading
```

flag, both on command line and GRAILS_OPTS.

According to docs, this should have worked
https://grails.org/wiki/Auto%20Reloading

And the answer accepted as the correct one here
[how can I disable reloading in a grails 3.0.0 app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28855946/how-can-i-disable-reloading-in-a-grails-3-0-0-app)
does not work either.

Have anyone actually succeeded in disabling auto-reloading in Grails 3.1?
(And successfully configured Grails 3 with JRebel?)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In 3.x apps you can disable Spring Loaded by adding

```
grails {
   agent {
      enabled = false
   }
}
```

to `build.gradle`.

Answer (score 4):

Burt's answer is correct related to the question -> how to disable autoreloading.

However, Anton's answer is relevant to the second/related issue on getting Jrebel to work.

I now have a working example, which works with both

```
gradle bootRun -Pjrebel   -> disable springloaded, using jrebel
gradle bootRun            -> uses springloaded
```

and

```
grails
grails> run-app
```

My config is a combination of

```
export GRAILS_OPTS="-javaagent:$JREBEL_HOME/jrebel.jar -Drebel.base=/Users/<username>/.jrebel"
```

and build.gradle

```
rebel {
  alwaysGenerate = false
  showGenerated = true
//rebelXmlDirectory = "build/classes"
}

if (project.hasProperty('jrebel')) {
  bootRun.dependsOn(generateRebel)
  grails {
    agent {
      enabled = false
    }
  } 
  tasks.withType(JavaExec) {
    jvmArgs "-javaagent:jrebel.jar"
    jvmArgs "-Xverify:none"
  }
}
```

Thanks @burt-beckwith and @anton-arhipov for your input!

Answer (score 3):

To enable JRebel for Grails 3 project you need to configure -javaagent argument with the corresponding path the jrebel.jar in build.gradle file:

```
tasks.withType(JavaExec) { jvmArgs "-javaagent:jrebel.jar" }
```