# Gradle DSL for Grails 3.x

Tags: grails, gradle, grails-3.1

Does anybody know where to find the documentation for Grails 3.x's Gradle DSL?

I have seen it referenced, e.g in a separate post
-> [Disable reloading in Grails 3.1 / springloaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35226076/disable-reloading-in-grails-3-1-springloaded)

However, can't find it in the docs, and the Grails Gradle plugin sites

https://github.com/grails/grails-gradle-plugin

http://grails.github.io/grails-gradle-plugin/docs/manual/

seems relevant only for the 2.x versions of Grails.

**Edit**

To be more clear.

**What I'm looking for is the configuration options available within the grails block in a build.gradle script.**

```
grails {
  //which options are available here??
}
```

E.g. I know this specific config works, as it is mentioned in the post linked above

```
grails {
    agent {
        enabled = false
    }
}
```

However, these config options are not documented anywhere (where I can find them)

Comment: Are you looking for this: https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/ ?

Comment: No, that's Gradle's own DSL. I'm looking for the DSL for Grails. E.g. spring-boot provides documentation for their Gradle plugin - https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/build-tool-plugins-gradle-plugin.html - as does Jacoco - https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/jacoco_plugin.html. So basically I'm interested in the grails {} block within a gradle script. (and possibly other config blocks related to Grails)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, plugin documentation is still in (slow) progress. But you can see the available properties and respective docs in the plugin javadoc, starting at the GrailsExtension class:

https://grails.github.io/grails-gradle-plugin/latest/api/org/grails/gradle/plugin/core/GrailsExtension.html

Currently they are:

- GrailsExtension.Agent    agent Configure the reloading agent
- boolean  exploded Whether to include subproject dependencies as directories directly on the classpath, instead of as JAR files
- boolean  native2ascii
  Whether to invoke native2ascii on resource bundles
- boolean  native2asciiAnt
  Whether to use Ant to do the conversion
- boolean  packageAssets
  Whether assets should be packaged in META-INF/assets for plugins
- boolean  pathingJar
  Whether to create a jar file to reference the classpath to prevent classpath too long issues in Windows