# Disabling dynamicReload/developmentModeWatch in Grails4/5 for DEV Environemnt

Tags: grails

I would like to disable the dynamic reload mechanism in Grails4/5.

In my case it's not effective enough so I rather avoid all the `"File {} changed, recompiling..."` messages

I'm very well aware of suggestions like  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41400721/1788766)
to put `grails.agent.enabled = false` in `build.gradle`

but this seems not to work.

I found in the [source code](https://github.com/grails/grails-core/blob/47ef7853399ec6d36eaa216578bcb25155676119/grails-core/src/main/groovy/grails/boot/GrailsApp.groovy#L109) this if condition:

```
        if(environment.isReloadEnabled()) {
            log.debug("Reloading status: {}", environment.isReloadEnabled())
            enableDevelopmentModeWatch(environment, applicationContext)
            environment.isDevtoolsRestart()
        }
```

with getting the value [here](https://github.com/grails/grails-core/blob/464a532d37fd81ccd8ec79a1f76a9657bfed5992/grails-bootstrap/src/main/groovy/grails/util/Environment.java#L675-L681):

```
    public boolean isReloadEnabled() {
        final boolean reloadOverride = Boolean.getBoolean(RELOAD_ENABLED);
        getReloadLocation();
        final boolean reloadLocationSpecified = hasLocation(reloadLocation);
        return this == DEVELOPMENT && reloadLocationSpecified ||
                reloadOverride && reloadLocationSpecified;
    }
```

but this pretty much always evaluates to `true`.

The `reloadLocation` will always be *something* where reloadOverride will be always `null`

Comment: The `grails.agent.reload` question you point to is addressing Grails 3, when Spring Loaded was configured in the project by default.  The question here is addressing Grails 4/5, versions for which that is not the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools` from your dependencies.

Comment: hey @jeff-scott-brown I did removed it but this print statement is stil being reached https://github.com/grails/grails-core/blob/464a532d37fd81ccd8ec79a1f76a9657bfed5992/grails-core/src/main/groovy/grails/boot/GrailsApp.groovy#L386

Comment: Do you have a reloading agent configured in the project?